# Generate combinations (actually products) sorted in increasing maximum item order

Tags: python

The first function below does what I want, but not very efficiently.

It generates products ordered so that lists containing larger elements are generated later.

The first one unnecessarily generates combinations that are discarded. How to make it efficient? A better algorithm would be nice.

```
import itertools

def prods(base, length, start = 0):
  for b in xrange(start + 1, base + 1):
    for comb in [list(reversed(item)) for item in itertools.product(xrange(b), repeat = length)]:
      if max(comb) == (b - 1):
        yield comb

>>> for val in prods(3, 2): print val
[0, 0]  # 0's start here
[1, 0]  # 1's start here
[0, 1]
[1, 1]
[2, 0]  # 2's start here
[2, 1]
[0, 2]
[1, 2]
[2, 2]

>>> for val in prods(3, 2, 2): print val
[2, 0]  # 2's start here
[2, 1]
[0, 2]
[1, 2]
[2, 2]
```

Here is another (partial) solution, it is not very memory efficient, but nothing is discarded.

```
import itertools

def prods2(base, length):
  for comb in sorted([list(reversed(item)) for item in itertools.product(xrange(base), repeat = length)], key=max):
    yield comb

>>> for val in prods2(3, 2): print val
[0, 0]  # 0's start here
[1, 0]  # 1's start here
[0, 1]
[1, 1]
[2, 0]  # 2's start here
[2, 1]
[0, 2]
[1, 2]
[2, 2]
```

By the way, is there a name for such ordering?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
from itertools import product

vs = range(3)

def compare(x,y):

    mx = cmp(max(x), max(y))
    sc = cmp(x[1], y[1])

    if mx == 0:
         return sc
    return mx

for p in sorted(product(vs, vs), cmp=compare):
    print p
```

You want to compare on the maximum value first. If there's a tie, compare the second values and finally the first values.

The ordering is not a *degree reverse lexicographical* ordering, because you compare the maximum of the tuples and not the sum. I suppose you could call it an *exponent reverse lexicographical* ordering; but don't quote me on it.

Comment: Since combinations are usually exponentially growing, OP is probably looking for an in-order generation algorithm instead of a post-generation sort.

Comment: Yes, also the ability to set the starting point is important.

Comment: This is essentially same approach as my second and incomplete solution. Generate products and then sort them.

Answer (score 0):

I originally wanted to write this completely independently from itertools, but actually I was doing far too much. The nice thing about itertools is that it’s all based on generators, so nothing is stored. So we can actually run `itertools.product` multiple times and just filter based on the contents of the results.

So how can we solve this problem? We first get all combinations from `[0]`. Then we get all *new* combinations from `[0, 1]`. Then we get all the *new* combinations from `[0, 1, 2]` etc. We just need to make sure that we get the “new” part done correctly. And for that, we just need to make sure that the highest number is part of the combination.

```
def prods (num, length):
    for i in range(num + 1):
        # get all product combinations …
        for c in itertools.product(range(i + 1), repeat=length):
            # … but only select the ones where the current number is contained
            if i in c:
                yield c
```

This results in a slightly different order (one that actually makes more sense to me), but the overall idea is still there:

```
>>> for x in prods(3, 2):
        print(x)

(0, 0) # <- 0 starts
(0, 1) # <- 1 starts
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
(0, 2) # <- 2 starts
(1, 2)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
(0, 3) # <- 3 starts
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
(3, 0)
(3, 1)
(3, 2)
(3, 3)
```

Comment: This is essentially the same approach as my fully working first solution. Generate products and discard the ones that we don't want to see anymore.

Comment: @karu No, it’s not the same, my solution requires constant memory.